# If statement best practice

Tags: java, if-statement

Consider the following function which assign a value to the `string str` depending on the value of the parameter `i`. Which of the following case is the best practice, if any :

```
public void myfunction(int i, bool condition)
{
    string str = "default";
    if(condition && i == 0) { str = "The value is 0"; }
    if(condition && i == 100) {str = "The value is 100"; }
}
```

or

```
public void myfunction(int i, bool condition)
{
    string str;
    if(condition && i == 0) 
    {
        str = "The value is 0";
    }
    else if(condition && i == 100)
    {
        str = "The value is 100";
    }
    else
    {
        str = "default";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "best practice" for this.  It is a matter of opinion / personal taste.

Comment: Is your question mainly about the spacing, or about the actual statements? Also: there is an `&&` missing in the second example.

Comment: Personally I'd use repeated conditional operators...

Comment: At least using the `else if` in the second example is better than the first. In the first example `condition && i == 100)` is tested for even if you could already return when `i == 0`.

Comment: @StephenC that's what I wanted to know, I was wondering if appart for the readability and personnal preference, the "else if" statement was more efficient

Comment: As already stated by @Yellow, the second example is better for avoiding unnecesary tests, important for cases where performance is crucial and the workload is considerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically between your two examples, neither is objectively better than the other. It is very subjective. I think the second one is more readable.

However, a better way to do what you are doing is to create a `Map` with your `int` -> `String` mapping and use that.

```
static Map<Integer, String> valueMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
static {
    valueMap.put(1, "The value is 0");
    ...
    valueMap.put(100, "The value is 100");
}

public void myfunction(int i, bool condition)
{
    string str = "default";
    if(condition) {
        str = valueMap.get(i);  // Also do checks if the value is not found etc.
    }
}
```

If your values are really something like "value is i", you should just use the int to construct the value. (`"value is " + i`)

Comment: In my opinion to initialize a static map like this is blowing up your code and needs more memory consumption. if you don't have some much specific cases then i would prefer to put the string directly.

Comment: Probably the best answer here! and it got down voted. People don't down vote for no reason(even if the answer is not the best one for you, it is NOT wrong). Voted up!

Comment: @NeoP5 Then assign it directly! You don't have to use the map.
You can allways do: `str = "The value is " + i;`

Comment: @DimaMaligin i didnt say it is wrong. it is definitely a correct solution; i just said it depends on how long you static map will be. its related to personal flavor and code esthetics

Comment: @NeoP5 I didn't say that YOU downvoted. I actually wrote the comment before seeing yours. So it wasn't intended for you.

Comment: Btw you can also do it like: 

`string str = condition ? ("The value is " + i) : "default";`

Answer (score 3):

what about switch/case statement. something like....

```
public String myFunction(int i, boolean condition) {
    String str = "default";
    if (condition) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                str = "The value is 0";
                break;
            case 100:
                str = "The value is 100";
                break;
            default:
                str = "default";
                break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Default case is not needed inside the switch. You are initializing it to the default value. Also a break is missing

Comment: of courser there is a "break" missing for case == 100!!!

Comment: I thought about it but assining the value of str twice if default seemed redondant

Comment: @KodingKid yes indeed. just wanted to show that this is possible. in that we you can even define an other default value if condition == true and one for condition == false; but anyway in this case your are right :)

Comment: added the missing break;

Answer (score 1):

How about using the switch statement for this?

```
public String myFunction(int i, boolean condition)
{
    String str = "";
    if (condition)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                str = "The value is 0";
                break;
            case 100:
                str = "The value is 100";
                break;
            default:
                str = "default";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate answer, @NeoP5 already gave the same answer.

Comment: Oops! the same was posted by NeoP5 minutes before :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I whould say that there's no big difference between the two but depending on the context of your code, for example (if you have to test those conditions for several Strings ...) but for sure the second vesion should be better because it avoids the test `(condition && i == 100)` if `i==0` .

Answer (score 0):

Both styles have their own advantages. The first one is shorter and (maybe) easier to read, but the second one is easier to debug:

```
if(condition && i == 0) 
{
    str = "The value is 0"; // You can put breakpoint here
}
```